# Flask-Mongoengine API Pagination

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I'm using MongoDB and Flask to make a JSON API for a mobile app.

When the app calls /topics/ it will return a list of topics, but how do i paginate the results efficiently? MongoEngine provides a offset and limit, but that grabs the whole result set before limiting and such, which is not very efficient if we have thousands of documents.

```
@app.route('/topics/<int:limit>/<int:page>', methods=['GET'])
def get_topics(limit=25, page=1):
    if limit is None or limit <= 1: 
        limit = 2

    if page is None or page <= 1:
        page = 1

    offset = (page - 1) * limit
    topics = Topic.objects().limit(limit).skip(offset)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, mongoengine does queries with `limit` and `skip` parameters in mongodb. You can verify that by using [explain](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.explain) to the query and have it return the [execution plan](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#core-explain-output) instead of the results.

Comment: Yeah i know it can do it, i'm just saying, i'm not sure if that's efficient if it grabs all objects and filters them.

Comment: No really, use `explain` (or wireshark if you want to)to check, the query to mongodb already contains the limit and skip